# how to query one node only in xml and php?

Tags: php, mysql, xml, dom

I have a code :

> $query = '//Document/Status[. = "Posted"]';
>   $names = $xpath->query($query);                                 // A
>   list of matched elements

result

> ```
> <Document>
>   <Company>SEC</Company>
>   <Type description="Misc Customer Invoices">CINV</Type>
>   <DocumentID>CI_INV000239562</DocumentID>
>   <DocumentDescription>Invoice</DocumentDescription>
>   <Status>Posted</Status>
>   <Owner>42570935</Owner>
>   <Customer>42570935</Customer>
>   <Location>42570935</Location>
>   <Date>20111115</Date>
>   <DueDate>20111115</DueDate>
>   <OpenDate>20111115</OpenDate>
>   <RequiredDate>20111115</RequiredDate>
>   <TaxCode>AUS GST</TaxCode>
>   <TaxType>Incl</TaxType>
>   <TaxRate>10.00</TaxRate>
>   <CurrencyCode>AUD</CurrencyCode>
>   <SubTotal>115.00</SubTotal>
>   <TotalTax>11.50</TotalTax>
>   <Total>126.50</Total>
>   <AmountDue>126.50</AmountDue>
>   <AmountPaid>126.50</AmountPaid>
> </Document>
> ```

If I want to display

> ```
>   <DocumentID>CI_INV000239562</DocumentID>
> ```

only

What should I do ?

If I want more node to be displayed ?
for example AmmountDue ?

> $query = '//Document/Status[. = "Posted"]/../DocumentID/AmmountDue';

Is this possible or I must use another method ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are few ways to do this, here is one of the example :-

```
$query = '//Document/Status[. = "Posted"]/../DocumentID';
...
$names = $xpath->query($query);
foreach ($names as $name)
{
  $node = $name->nodeValue; // string of "CI_INV000239562"
}
```

To seek for multiple node name :-

> //Document/Status[. = "Posted"]/../*[self::DocumentID or self::AmountDue]

Comment: If I want to add more for example AmmountDue ? $query = '//Document/Status[. = "Posted"]/../DocumentID/AmmountDue';

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = '//Document/Status[. = "Posted"]/DocumentID';
```